# Как работает Traffic git hub

Tags: git, github

Из интереса зашел в свой репозиторий на git в Traffic. Вижу такой график
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала я решил, что unique visitors - это уникальные посетители, а unique cloners это количество клонирований репозитория, произведенной разными людьми. Но судя по графику сегодня было 8 уникальных клонирований, а уникальный посетитель только один. Я видимо что-то не понимаю( Кто может объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Visitors* - могут отображаться как с git clone, так и при посещении страницы. А *unique visitors* - только те, кто перешел на ваш репозиторий из браузера, и провел на странице некоторое время. Те, кто зайдя в репозиторий сразу вышел - автоматически считаются *Visitors*